# Mongoose TypeError: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'pluralization' in undefined

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, schema, typeerror

Not really sure what's going on here. I see that others have encountered this error before, but I guess I just don't understand enough to draw parallels between what they were doing wrong and what I'm doing wrong.

This is just a simple project to learn the MERN stack. The objective here is relatively simple: upload a PDF file to a mongoDB database, retrieve that PDF file, and display it to a preview window. Possibly an iframe, or something simpler, depending on the options available to me. At the moment, my primary issue is with the back end.

So, here is my code:

index.js (username and password omitted, of course):

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import { router } from './routes/image-route.js';

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "20mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "20mb", extended: true}));

app.use('./routes/image-route.js', router)

app.use(cors());

const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.xxpzv.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL).then(() => console.log("SERVER CONNECTION ESTABLISHED"));
}

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening at port ${port}`));
```

image_model.js:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const imageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    img:
    {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
});

const imageData = mongoose.model('image', 'imageSchema')

export { imageData };
```

image-route.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import { getImage, postImage } from '../controllers/image_controller.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', getImage);
router.post('/', postImage);

export { router };
```

image_controller.js:

```
import { imageData } from '../models/image_model.js';

export const getImage = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allImages = await imageData.find();
        req.status(200).json(allImages);
        console.log('Successfully submitted');
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({message: error.message});
    }
}

export const postImage = async (req, res) => {
    const image = req.body;
    const newImage = new imageData(image);

    try {
        await newImage.save();
        res.status(201).json(newImage);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({message: error.message});
    }
}
```

And this is the error I'm receiving when I attempt to start the server:

[image]

I'm not really sure what else to say. I've tried the solutions I've seen for similar problems (to the best of my understanding), but their problems were apparently not quite the same as mine. If there's anything else anyone needs to know to help me with this, I'll provide whatever is necessary. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

file: `image_model.js`

```js
const imageData = mongoose.model('image', 'imageSchema')
 // imageSchema is not a string
```

change to:

```js
const imageData = mongoose.model('image', imageSchema)
```